# Create multiple ERC-20 tokens without deploy a contract everytime?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I would like to write a smart contract that can issue an erc20 token when asked (with some required parameter, as name, symbol, decimals, and owner address).

From what I understood I have to deploy a new smart contract every time I want to issue a new ERC-20 token. Can I do this inside a smart contract?

I also saw that there is this new erc1155 standard, but from what I understand is mostly for issuing erc721 tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is, for example:

```
contract ERC20Token {
    string  public name;
    string  public symbol;
    uint8   public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    constructor(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _totalSupply) public {
        ...
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value public returns (bool) {
        ...
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value (bool) {
        ...
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) (bool) {
        ...
    }
}

contract ERC20TokenFactory {
    function createToken(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _totalSupply) public returns (ERC20Token) {
        return new ERC20Token(_name, _symbol, _decimals, _totalSupply);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Do I need to extend the ERC20 interface or some openzeppelin library?

Comment: @Agilulfo: You're welcome. You can do whatever you like, as long as it conforms to the [ERC20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20). OpenZeppelin has it all implemented, including the `IERC20` interface (which can be useful elsewhere in your code), Safe-Math handling and so forth. So yes, you may as well use it. I did not specify this in my answer, because it was not in the context of your question.